# How to change widget's form color in admin?

Tags: widgets, admin, css

I have a simple question. How to change widget's form color in admin panel of wordpress (on widgets page) to make them more unique? 
Here is a simple example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Register/enqueue an admin stylesheet](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes#The_Admin_Style_Sheet)

```
function my_admin_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-admin-theme', get_template_directory_uri().'/admin-style.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_theme_style');
```

### Then add rules of the form

```
#widget-list div[id*="_archives-"], div[id*="_archives-"] {
  background:red;
}
```

Consider that proof of concept. I will leave it up to you to target the precise elements you want.

Comment: God damn, that was so easy.. I already forgot how powerful may be sometimes css selectors. Thank, I'm very appreciated, works like a charm!